# Why is heparin contraindicated in patients with severe hypertension?

Tags: blood, blood-pressure, blood-circulation, hypertension, coagulation

Heparin is a parenteral anti coagulant- prevents clot formation by inhibiting factors 2 a and 10 a mainly. Now, patients with severe uncontrolled hypertension- have persistent bp of more than 140/90. Here we are considering the force exerted by the blood on the wall of the arteries. Increased pressure of blood means, blood is trying to flow through a smaller diameter of the vessel, hence you can say that blood flow is decreased in such patients. Shouldn't heparin be useful in patients of hypertension because it will prevent clots from blocking the blood flow ? Why is it contraindicated ?

Answer (score -2):

Pelo aumento de pressão exercida pelas paredes dos vasos haverá maior probabilidade de rotura.. podendo causar AVC hemorrágico

[Translated:

By increasing the pressure exerted by the walls of the vessels there will be a greater probability of rupture.. may cause hemorrhagic AVC (Arrhythmogenic ventricular cardiomyopathy)]

Comment: Este es un sitio en Inglés. Todas las publicaciones deben estar en Inglés.

Comment: Also, although I believe your answer is correct, we require supporting references here. Can you please edit your answer to 1) translate it to English, and 2) add at least one supporting reference.